# Magento for franchises

Tags: magento

I have a Magento store, very successful, I sell locally (and I'm the deliverer), only on my selected postal codes in my table rates.

I want to expand and not only limit to my very very small service area (Westside). 
I'll soon start operating in the eastside of my city, and I'll hire a branch manager to operate east side store (and deliver the goods) while I still operate westside.

I don't want my east side manager to know my sales, but I, as owner want to know global sales.

Is there a magento option or a plugin that will allow me to set admin accounts to diferent branches (or warehouses)?

IF ITS STILL NOT CLEAR-------------------------------------

Imagine I'm a small pizza delivery business

- I want my pizza ordered from area A to be operated from admin account A
- I want my pizza ordered from area B to be operated from admin account B

Still want global admin account to keep track of sales from all areas

---

I have seen some Magento plugins that help me manage diferent warehouses and some others that allow me to manage drop shippers

cut long story short...is there a plugin that would help me manage different branches?

Answer (score 0):

Here i would like to suggest one very usefull extention for advanced permission to manage your store

[Advanced Permissions for Community Edition](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html)

it is paid extension, but before buy, i am requesting you to go throw all functionality providing by this extention.

Please let me know if i can assist you.

Comment: Terrific! i dont mind paid extensions, ill check it out, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks @SergioLozanoGarza
would you place accept my answer, if it is useful to you, i would be glad if you do.. :)